# XSL decoding html escape sequence

Tags: xslt

i am using XSL file to reformat XML file( output XML file in different format ) my problem is some of the node contain Unicode charters in html escape sequence (ї) and when i use XSL these Unicode get decoded and transformed to their actual values and i need them to stay as html escape sequence (ї)

i tried this,but it didnt work and it got decoded i need the html escape sequence to stay as it is for later processing

```
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
<xsl:copy>
<xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" disable-output-escaping="yes" />
</xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

thank you in advance,

Comment: Is this numeric character reference like `&#169;` or `&#xa9;` ?

Answer (score 2):

Don't use disable-output-escaping unless you understand what it means - it's not magic fairy dust. Your complaint is that characters aren't being escaped where you want them escaped, so disabling escaping is hardly going to help.

The XSLT processor doesn't know which characters were escaped in the input and which weren't - the XML parser doesn't supply that information. So if you really want the output to reflect the input exactly, the only way to achieve it is to preprocess the XML before the XML parser sees it. One way to do this is the lexev preprocessor from Andrew Welch.

More usually, people want non-ASCII characters escaped whether or not they were escaped in the input, and that can be achieved by setting the output encoding to us-ascii - provided there are no non-ASCII characters in element names or comments, which would cause an error.

Answer (score 0):

`disable-output-escaping` should be "no" by default and only applies to `xsl:value-of` and `xsl:text` elements.  Not all XSLT processors are required to support it.

XSLT 2.0 deprecated output escaping and introduced the concept of ["character maps"](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt20/#character-maps).  However, not all XSLT processors can use XSLT 2.0, and adoption has been somewhat limited.  Depending on what you're using, your XSLT processor may not support XSLT 2.0.  I'd look into it.